# is there a way to perform face recognition on images stored in firebase storage using python

Tags: python, firebase-storage, face-recognition

i want to access the images in my firebase storage, encode the images and perform a face recognition from a webcam.

```
import pyrebase
from google.cloud import storage
import os
import cv2
import numpy as np
from pathlib import Path
import face_recognition as fr
known_name_list=[]
known_image_list=[]
known_encoded_list = []
image_path_list=[]
def Encode_Images_from_Storage():
    storage_client = storage.Client.from_service_account_json("facerecognition.json")
    bucket = storage_client.get_bucket("address to my storage")
    source_folder = "StaffImages" # name of folder on cloud
    blobs = list(bucket.list_blobs(prefix=source_folder)) # list images in the folder
    for blob in blobs:
        image_path = blob.name # separate the name from the file path
        image_data = Path(image_path) # convert the image to file path
        image_name = image_data.name # get the name only
        known_name_list.append(image_name)
        image_path_list.append(image_path)
        print(image_path_list)
    for img in image_path_list:
        image_read = cv2.imread(img )
        known_image_list.append(image_read)
```

i want the images to be added to list know_image_list and then i can encode the images from thee list but i keep getting this error.
[ WARN:0@9.835] global loadsave.cpp:248 cv::findDecoder imread_('StaffImages/Joshua.jpg'): can't open/read file: check file path/integrity
[None, None]